# PHP - How to print errors on login form on index page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, authentication

Ok, so this question is kind of hard to word, but i'll try my best. So I currently have an index.php page with a pop-up login form and I have login.php with all the login php stuff to deal with the request. At the moment I can only seem to print login errors on the login.php page, which opens up a blank white page with just the errors on that, due to the fact that the form action on my index.php form is set to "login.php" which deals with the login stuff.. What I want is to print the erros on the login form in my index.php, but have the login.php deal with the rest of the php. I hope that kind of makes sense.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
                <label>Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="email"/>
                <br />

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password"/>
                <br />
                <!--<?php 
                    if(empty($errors)===false){
                        echo output_errors($errors);    
                    }
                ?>-->
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="remember" type="checkbox" />
                    <label for="remember">Keep me signed in</label>
                </div>

                <div class="action_btns">
                    <div class="one_half last"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-blue" value="Login"></div>
                    <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" id="register_form" class="btn">Sign up</a></div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Above is the code for my form on the index.php page. the commented out php in that is where I want to print the errors.
Below is my login.php

```
    <?php
include 'init.php';


function sanitize($data){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

function output_errors($errors){
    return '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $errors).'</li></ul>';
}

//check if user exists
function user_exists($email){
        $email = sanitize($email);
        return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM register WHERE email = '$email'"),0) == 1)? true : false;
}

//check if user has activated account
function user_activate($email){
        $email = sanitize($email);
        return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM register WHERE email = '$email' AND active =1"),0) == 1)? true : false;
}
function user_id_from_email($email){
    $email = sanitize($email);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM register WHERE email = '$email'"),0,'id'));
}
function login($email,$password){
    $user_id = user_id_from_email($email);
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM register WHERE email = '$email' AND password ='$password'"),0) == 1)? $user_id : false;
}


if(empty($_POST)=== false){
    $email = $_POST['email'];   
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

if(empty($email)|| empty($password) === true){
        $errors[] = "You must enter a username and a password"; 
}
else if(user_exists($email) === false){
    $errors[] = "Email address is not registered";  
}
else if(user_activate($email) === false){
    $errors[] = "You haven't activated your account yet";   
}
else{
    $login = login($email, $password);
    if($login === false){
        $errors[] = "email/password are incorrect";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
if(empty($errors)===false){
    header('Location: index.php');
    echo output_errors($errors);    
}

?>
```

This is my init.php below too which stores the array.

```
    <?php
session_start();
error_reporting();
require 'connection.php';

$errors = array();

?>
```

Comment: most likely you should be storing the errors in $_SESSION, and your login script should check for that. but you also have no `session_start()` in your code, so the session stuff you do have is essentially useless anyways.

Comment: I do have session_start in my init.php and logout.php

Comment: which bit should I store in $_session?

Comment: $errors, since that's where you're sticking all of the error messages.

Comment: Do NOT use `MySQL_*` it has been removed and will not work anymore. Use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or `MySQLi` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: so how would you rewrite my statement: return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM register WHERE email = '$email'"),0,'id'));
using mysqli?

Answer (score 1):

A tip before I start is to never put variables that are not constant into prepared statements, you're allowing user input directly to your SQL statements.

But more to the point, if you want to receive errors, I'd suggest you use a basic `die($db->error);` where you want to return an error via the database.

Always remember to `$db->close();` at the end of working with a connection.